# run angularjs project using visual studio 2012

Tags: angularjs, node.js, visual-studio-2012, node-modules

I am new in AngularJS and I have to create Dashboard with many graphs. So I am using the below theme for my project.

https://startangular.com/product/flatlogic-angular-material-dashboard/

For this I just download this theme source and extract this zip file than open with Visual Studio 2012.
When I run this project It shows me below screen.
[image]

So how can I run this project?

I am using Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 10 machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to follow the instructions on [this page](https://github.com/flatlogic/angular-material-dashboard/blob/master/README.md). Use `gulp serve` instead of VS's built-in webserver.

Comment: I don't know about that gulp serve. Can you please guide me for this?

Comment: you need to install gulp package globally `npm install -g gulp`. Then just run `gulp serve` from the project's directory.

Comment: And make sure you installed ruby before running `gem install sass`. Otherwise `gulp serve` won't work.

Comment: When I run "gulp serve" it gives the error "Error: Error: jquery is not installed. Try running `bower install`"

Comment: oh, then you also need to install bower. Run `npm install -g bower`. Then `bower install`.

Comment: I already installed bower -g and when I run bower install it gives the output "bower angular-touch#^1.5.0      ENOGIT git is not installed or not in the PATH"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131597/discussion-between-jstice4all-and-user3441151).